# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

The following is the code that tries to modify the input supplied by a user by using sockets:

```
from socket import *

serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

When I execute it and supply input the following error occurs:

```
Input lowercase sentence:fdsgfdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\srinath files\NETWORKS\UDPclient.py", line 6, in <module>
    clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: The first argument (`message`) needs to be bytes, but you're passing a string.  You should encode it before sending e.g. `message.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: but the thing is i need to pass string to the server not byte

Comment: from socket import *
serverName = 'hostname'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input('Input lowercase sentence:')
message.encode('utf-8')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()

Comment: i got the same error

Comment: The thing that goes on the wire is _always_ bytes.  The server needs to be able to make sense of those bytes somehow.

Comment: That's because `message` is still a string.  You need something like `clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), ...)`

Answer (score 99):

This code is good for Python 2. But in Python 3, results in bit encoding error. I was trying to make a simple TCP server and encountered the same problem. Encoding solves this. Try this with `sendto` command.

```
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
```

Similarly you should use `.decode()` to receive the data on the UDP server side, if you want to print it exactly as it was sent.

Comment: would encoding and decoding on both sides of the connection increase latency? If so would python2 actually be faster at sending data than python3

Comment: In my opinion, this will not affect the performance such as latency etc. However, I haven't tried experimented with it myself so I can't be sure about that.

Comment: Did python do this just to support emoji  in their native String class? I guess good for internationalization re: `message.encode('utf-16')` and 

Answer (score 34):

Encoding and decoding can solve this in Python 3:

Client Side:

```
>>> host='127.0.0.1'
>>> port=1337
>>> import socket
>>> s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect((host,port))
>>> st='connection done'
>>> byt=st.encode()
>>> s.send(byt)
15
>>>
```

Server Side:

```
>>> host=''
>>> port=1337
>>> import socket
>>> s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.bind((host,port))
>>> s.listen(1)
>>> conn ,addr=s.accept()
>>> data=conn.recv(2000)
>>> data.decode()
'connection done'
>>>
```

Comment: See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html to understand why this changed in Python 3.

Answer (score 14):

A bit of encoding can solve this:

Client Side:

```
message = input("->")
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (address, port))
```

Server Side:

```
data = s.recv(1024)
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(message.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Your client won't work: sendto requires 3 parameters, the message the server address and the related port

Comment: Message, address, and port. Seems like 3 parameters to me and works on mine! :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply replace message parameter passed  in `clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))` to `clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))`. Then you would successfully run in in *python3*

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you encounter an error with this message *use [`my_string.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)*.

<sup><sup>(where `my_string` is the string you're passing to a function/method).</sup></sup>

The `encode` method of `str` objects returns the encoded version of the string as a [`bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) which you can then use. 
In this specific instance, socket methods [such as `.send`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) *expect a bytes object* as the data to be sent, *not a string object*.

Since you have an object of type `str` and you're passing it to a function/method that expects an object of type `bytes`, an error is raised  that clearly explains that:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So the `encode` method of strings is needed, applied on a `str` value and returning a `bytes` value:

```
>>> s = "Hello world"
>>> print(type(s))
<class 'str'>
>>> byte_s = s.encode()
>>> print(type(byte_s))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(byte_s)
b"Hello world"
```

Here the prefix `b` in `b'Hello world'` denotes that this is indeed a bytes object. You can then pass it to whatever function is expecting it in order for it to run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

add "b" in your sending data like this:
request = **client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")**