# another TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm a complete newbie in Python, but I have been programming for fun in (Liberty-)Basic since about 1980.

Using Python 3.5.2 I was testing this script:

```
import time, telnetlib

host    = "dxc.ve7cc.net"
port    = 23
timeout = 9999

try:
    session = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)
except socket.timeout:
    print ("socket timeout")
else:
    session.read_until("login: ")
    session.write("on0xxx\n")
    output = session.read_some()
    while output:
        print (output)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # let the buffer fill up a bit
        output = session.read_some()
```

Can anyone tell me why I get the *TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'* and how I can solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003498/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 (but *not* in Python 2), [`str` and `bytes` are distinct types](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html) that can't be mixed.  You can't write a `str` directly to a socket; you have to use `bytes`.  Simply prefix the string literal with `b` to make it a `bytes` literal.

```
session.write(b"on0xxx\n")
```

Comment: this is what I needed, thanks! I also had to add the 'b' here:     session.write(b"on0xxx\n")

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Python 2.x, where you don't need to encode the data sent through the net, you have to in Python 3.x.
So everything you want to send needs to be encoded with the .encode() function. Everything you receive needs to be decoded with .decode().