# Python Socket Programming Simple Web Server, Trying to access a html file from server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, python-requests

So, i am trying to create a simple server on python and trying to access a html file in the same directory through it, but as the output i keep on getting ready to serve...
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaddz.png)

EDIT: 
Put an HTML file (e.g., HelloWorld.html) in the same directory that the server is in. Run the server program. Determine the IP address of the host that is running the server (e.g., 128.238.251.26). From another host, open a browser and provide the corresponding URL. For example:
http://128.238.251.26:6789/HelloWorld.html
‘HelloWorld.html’ is the name of the file you placed in the server directory. Note also the use of the port number after the colon. You need to replace this port number with whatever port you have used in the server code. In the above example, we have used the port number 6789. The browser should then display the contents of HelloWorld.html. If you omit ":6789", the browser will assume port 80 and you will get the web page from the server only if your server is listening at port 80.
Then try to get a file that is not present at the server. You should get a “404 Not Found” message.

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
#Prepare a sever socket
serverSocket.bind(('', 12006))
serverSocket.listen(1)
while True:
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    #Establish the connection
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')
        #Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: Your output is a __standart output__, that used through `print` function. you should to make a request to your server and you'll get the correct output

Comment: Oh thank you, but do i just use a random ip address?

Comment: no. If your server on your local machine, you should use `localhost` address; if not, you should use your server ip. Also you should to specify a port. 12006 in your case. `localhost:12006` as an example

Comment: I am getting an erroe now ``` TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ``` caused from this line ``` connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')  ```

Comment: Based on this last comment this is a duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003498/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str) and many similar questions (just google this error in connection with "socket").

Comment: This is not valid Python 3, as `print` is used as a statement, without parentheses. Either the code or the tags are wrong. I guess the TypeError won't be seen in Python 2, either.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is a **standart output**, that used through `print` function. you should to make a request to your server and you'll get the correct output

If your server on your local machine, you should use `localhost` address; if not, you should use your server ip. Also you should to specify a port. `12006` in your case. `localhost:12006` as an example

Also `socket.send` method requires a byte-like object. not string

If it's only a string [literal](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/string_literals.html), you should to add a `b` character before the first quotation mark

Example:

```py
connectionSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
```

If it is a `string` object, you should to *encode* it:

```py
connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, what i am trying to access is an basic html hello world file, will it be same thing.

Comment: can you edit your question(in comms)? I don't understand you